# ion-infinite-scroll firing extremely infrequently

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2, infinite-scroll

I am trying to get `ionInfiniteScroll` to work - I have already gotten it to work in several other places in my app, and this page is actually almost identical to another page where it is working fine. When I scroll down nothing happens, no loading graphic. I have a console message right on the inside of my `doInfinite` method and it never executes...so the doInfinite code is never executing. I'm thinking maybe there is something wrong with the html structure since the method doesn't execute:

```
<ion-content no-padding>
  <div (swipeLeft)="swipeLeft()" (swipeRight)="toFull()"> <!--(swipeRight)="toProfile()"-->

    ...

   <div class ='weeklydeals contentone' #weeklydeals [@moveList]='moveState'>
   <ion-list class="marginstatus" no-padding>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let a of promotions" no-padding>
      <div class="feedtoptextcontainer">
        <!--<div class="imageparent">
          <img class="postprofilepic" src="{{a.url}}">
        </div>-->
        <div class="usernamecontainer">
          <h4 class="postusername">@{{a.username}}</h4><br>
        </div>
        <h3 class="promotitle">{{a.title}}</h3>
        <div class="desccontainer">
          <h4 class="deal">{{a.caption}}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--<img class="imagepost" src="{{i}}">-->
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
   <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
   </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </div>

  ...

  <ion-item class="noavail" #noavail no-padding no-lines>NO RESULTS</ion-item>
</div>
```

**doInfinite method code:**

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log("in doinfinite promotionsssssss");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Begin async operation');
      /*console.log(this.content.directionY + "        upupupupupupu********");
      if(this.content.directionY == 'up') {
        this.show = false
      }
      else {
        this.show = true;
      }*/

      console.log(this.startAtKey1 + "     before %%^&^&^% start at");
      this.list2 = this.af.list('/promotions', {
      query: {
        orderByKey: true,
        endAt: this.startAtKey1,
        limitToLast: 11
      }});

      this.subscription11 = this.list2.subscribe(items => { 
          let x = 0;
          this.lastKey1 = this.startAtKey1;
          items.forEach(item => {


            let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('/settings/' + item.customMetadata.username + '/profilepicture.png');

            storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
              console.log(url + "in download url !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
              item.customMetadata.picURL = url;
            }).catch((e) => {
              console.log("in caught url !!!!!!!$$$$$$$!!");
              item.customMetadata.picURL = 'assets/blankprof.png';
            });

            if(this.startAtKey1 !== item.$key && this.lastKey1 !== item.$key) {
              console.log(this.startAtKey1 + "   :startAtKey1 before 4444444        item key:     " + item.$key);
              this.promotions.push(item.customMetadata); //unshift?**************
            }

            if(x == 0) {
              this.startAtKey1 = item.$key;
            }

            x++;
          });          

      })

      infiniteScroll.complete(); 

    }, 500);
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I think another important thing to note is that I am using 5 different lists that look like the one below...all on the same page (I only have included 2 below - that is what I was last testing with). Where the `...` is in the code, that are 4 more lists like the one you see above. They are all enclosed in `<div>`'s like the one above - and none of them are ever being displayed at the same time - I think I should post the whole `<ion-content>` just incase things are interfering with one another:

```
<ion-content no-padding>
<div (swipeLeft)="swipeLeft()" (swipeRight)="toFull()"> <!--(swipeRight)="toProfile()"-->



  <!--<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>-->


  <div class ='availability contentone' #availability [@moveList]='moveState'>
   <ion-list class="marginstatus" no-padding>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let z of availabilities" no-padding (tap)="presentProfileModal(z.salon, z.time)">
      <div class="feedtoptextcontainer">
        <div class="imageparent">
          <img class="postprofilepic" src="{{z.pic}}">
        </div>
        <div class="usernamecontainer">
          <h4 class="postusername">@{{z.salon}}</h4><br>
          <h4 class="poststudio">{{z.time}}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--<img class="imagepost" src="{{i}}">-->
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
  </div>

  <div class ='distance contentone' #distance [@moveList]='moveState'>
   <ion-list class="marginstatus" no-padding>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let z of distances" no-padding (tap)="presentProfileModalDistance(z.salon)">
      <div class="feedtoptextcontainer">
        <div class="imageparent">
          <img class="postprofilepic" src="{{z.pic}}">
        </div>
        <div class="usernamecontainer">
          <h4 class="postusername">@{{z.salon}}</h4><br>
          <h4 class="poststudio">{{z.distance}} mi</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--<img class="imagepost" src="{{i}}">-->
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
  </div>

  <div class ='ratings contentone' #ratings [@moveList]='moveState'>
   <ion-list class="marginstatus" no-padding>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let a of rating ; let i = index" no-padding (tap)="presentProfileModalRatings(a.username)">
      <div class="feedtoptextcontainer">
        <div class="imageparent">
          <img class="postprofilepic" src="{{a.picURL}}">
        </div>
        <div class="usernamecontainer">
          <h4 class="postusername">@{{a.username}}</h4><br>
          <h4 class="poststudio">{{a.stars}}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--<img class="imagepost" src="{{i}}">-->
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
  </div>

  <div class ='price contentone' #price [@moveList]='moveState'>
   <ion-list class="marginstatus" no-padding>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let a of pricesArray" no-padding (tap)="presentProfileModalPrice(a.username)">
      <div class="feedtoptextcontainer">
        <div class="imageparent">
          <img class="postprofilepic" src="{{a.picURL}}">
        </div>
        <div class="usernamecontainer">
          <h4 class="postusername">@{{a.username}}</h4><br>
          <h4 class="poststudio">{{a.price}}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--<img class="imagepost" src="{{i}}">-->
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
   <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfiniteP($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
   </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </div>

  <div class ='weeklydeals contentone' #weeklydeals [@moveList]='moveState'>
   <ion-list class="marginstatus" no-padding>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let a of promotions" no-padding>
      <div class="feedtoptextcontainer">
        <!--<div class="imageparent">
          <img class="postprofilepic" src="{{a.url}}">
        </div>-->
        <div class="usernamecontainer">
          <h4 class="postusername">@{{a.username}}</h4><br>
        </div>
        <h3 class="promotitle">{{a.title}}</h3>
        <div class="desccontainer">
          <h4 class="deal">{{a.caption}}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--<img class="imagepost" src="{{i}}">-->
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
   <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
   </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </div>

  <ion-item class="noavail" #noavail no-padding no-lines>NO RESULTS</ion-item>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

I switch the lists in and out by using `renderer` like `renderer.setElementStyle(el, 'display', 'none) or block`.

Comment: can you make a working example in https://stackblitz.com ? I dont see anything in your html

Comment: hey thanks...yah sure...ill let u know when its ready, haven't used stackblitz before.

Comment: I am trying to get the stackblitz working....here is the editable version...https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-trknv8 - basically i can't get it to recognize `angularfire2` `auth` and `database` packages, but `angularfire2` is installed - which are needed especially for ion-infinite-scroll...any ideas? feeduser.ts/feeduser.html is the only relevant page, the rest are stubs so that it would work...also a little ways down it is throwing an error at `keyboardControl: false`....also my code is very messy sorry - i was very rushed with this and didnt have much time with ionic before starting

Comment: @SurajRao - i have been unsuccessful setting up the stackblitz, it won't work if if the `angularfire2/auth .... /database` packages dont work....if u think u could fix this and have the time i could give u the git repo url...its public

Comment: You can add it in the dependencies section..

Comment: hey, i did...it doesnt recognize the /auth or /database as being part of angularfire2

Comment: Or Just try a small example... Not the entire project..

Comment: yah i just put in everything that the one page, `feeduser`, requires as stubs so i think its as small as i can get it...if i start taking out the angularfire2 code it wont compile for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be conflicting `css` that I had on `.scroll-content`. It seems if you add `css` to `.scroll-content`, `ion-infinite-scroll` stops working.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the issue!

Comment: problem is...i was using `margin-top: -xx%` to fix a bug where the top margin is like half the screen...and i can't think of another way to do it. a friend suggested i inject an element into the dom above scroll content and use `-margin-top` so im going to try that...let me know if you have any ideas...this will probably turn into another stack question :)